# How to use SMS in form

Tags: forms, laravel, sms

This concept is new to me but could be very useful for the app I am building. In wordpress there is a way to send sms texts through a whats called a gravity form http://www.textmarketer.co.uk/blog/2012/04/sms-news-ticker/wordpress-gravity-forms-sms-plugin/
How would I go about doing this in php using laravel. Does it cost money. Is there a free service?

Here is what I am looking to do.
User 1 fills out form and inputs number to send their input to number entered via sms from form
User 2 receives User's 1 text message from app online and has choice (interactive text message or could be text this "word" back to ) of three options for a response.
User's 2 response is updated on online app(displayed on front page) and entered into the database (what their choice is). Think of voting.
Thank you for all the input and suggestions.

Comment: Check out twilio.com - there are Laravel packages to integrate.

Comment: Thanks, I am already looking at Twilio, but I was hoping  I would find one with a free API.

Comment: @user3814409 You are unlikely to find a free API for this.

Comment: It looks like this may be the only option. Is there something I could do with node.js to somehow accomplish something similar. Not really specific, but I am having a difficult time thinking of what to ask.

Comment: I found the easiest best option for those of you curious: [here](https://www.tropo.com/)